# Pike Pushup: Hands and feet closer a healthy option?

Tags: exercise, muscle, strength, calisthenics

This is an example of Pike Pushups. One progression is to place your feet on a high platform to make it harder. I was curious if another method would be to have feet and hands vertical closer to together (so that the hands can almost touch the feet). Just curious if this is a safe and healthy option to increase load, because anytime I review resources, they never mention it as option.

[image]

Comment: To my understanding the goal is to get your hands as close to your feet as possible without bending your lower back to avoid pinching your discs. If you are getting very close to your feet, and don't have the balance for a full handstand, it is likely better to just move onto wall handstand pushups until you have the balance for handstands assuming that is what you are working towards.

Comment: I am just trying to increase the triceps and shoulder load for pushups cc @EricWarburton , not really trying for a handstand

Comment: Alright, most of what I said still stands. The goal is to get your feet closer and closer to your hands to increase load. When you get to the point where you don't have enough flexibility, to increase load you might have to move to handstands against the wall... or if you have access to a gym, use dumbbells or a shoulder press machine with heavier weights.

Comment: yeah, so its safe to push hand and feet together, and I should not pinch discs? I am just wondering because of the pinch disc reason people don't recommend, I was looking through many videos, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66x0qQiJ-MA.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ajna6AxQdtw. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnQU_lLBFW0.  @EricWarburton

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the research on this, that is why this is in comment form and not answer. I know that there are arguments that state when trying to touch toes, your lower back bends, causing your spine to pinch the discs together which can cause issues. I imagine the closer you get to your feet in the pike pushup, the more you would duplicate this issue. If someone else here knows something about this, feel free to correct me.

Comment: hi @EricWarburton when I tried close together, it made pushups harder, too much stress on the body, I believe its only for doing handstands, not sure myself, thats why I am asking